# Finding string after specific word for each cell in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help finding names within a sentence. In column A I have numerous sentences, each sentence may contain a "PM: {name}" substring, like below:

[image]

Some of the cells may not contain this, but for the ones that do I want to print the string name in column B beside each of the sentences in column A.

This is what I have so far but it only works for cell A2. I need it to work for all the cells that have "PM: Name" in column A.  (I wrote Sara for now manually)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PMName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim Reg1 As Object
    Dim RegMatches As Variant
    Dim Match As Variant
    Dim NextWord As Boolean
    Dim LR As Long

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With Reg1
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = "\w{1,50}"
        End With

        Set RegMatches = Reg1.Execute(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        NextWord = False '
        If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then
            For Each Match In RegMatches
                If NextWord Then
                    Cells(i, 2).Value = Match
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If UCase(Match) Like "PM" Then NextWord = True
            Next Match
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify about your input data? It's not clear what this data will look like, what is a "name", etc.  Screenshot of a few rows of data would be helpful, or edit your question to include some literal (not descriptive) examples.

Comment: David I have added an image

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, using a submatch (in brackets) to identify the specific bit you want to extract. I have also assumed only one match in each cell.

```
Sub Regex1()

Dim oRgx As Object, r As Range

Set oRgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With oRgx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "PM: (\w+)"
    For Each r In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If .Test(r) Then
            r.Offset(, 1) = .Execute(r)(0).submatches(0)
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by simply changing your pattern. This uses a non-capturing group to find a position in the string that matches `PM: <name>` and then by using the submatch function (The pattern in brackets) returns only the `<name>` part of that substring. This can also easily handle multiple matches by incrementing the `Offset` for each submatch

```
Public Sub PMName()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c, match, submatch

    With ActiveSheet ' Change this to your relevant sheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "(?:PM\:\s{0,}(\w{1,50}))"
        For Each c In rng
            If .test(c.Value2) Then
                For Each match In .Execute(c)
                    For Each submatch In match.submatches
                        Debug.Print match, submatch
                        c.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = submatch
                    Next submatch
                Next match
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If there were some cells that contained PM: Ash and also the number of PM ie. PM:1. How would I get it to ignore results that contain one character?

Comment: @IndushaSembakutti Change the pattern that has `\w{1,50}`  to `\w{2,50}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am new to VBA

Comment: @IndushaSembakutti No problem. All sorted now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may also do this without Regular Expressions:

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long, index As Long
Dim thisSentence As String
Dim words() As String

For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' normalize our sentence, upper-case and replace consecutive spaces
    thisSentence = Replace(UCase(Cells(i, 1).value), "  ", " ")
    words = Split(thisSentence, " ")
    index = arrayIndex(words, "PM:")
    If index >= 0 Then
        Cells(i, 2).value = words(index + 1)
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function arrayIndex(words() As String, value As String) As Long
' NOTE: If "PM:" is the LAST item in the words array, this will return a -1 value
'       because there is no "name" to return.
'
Dim ret As Long
Dim i As Long
ret = -1
For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words) - 1
    If words(i) = value Then
        ret = i
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If
Next
arrayIndex = ret
End Function
```

Output:

[image]